# Antlr can't be found when building Processing

Tags: software-installation, compiling, cpu

This is my error when building http://www.processing.org/:

```
BUILD FAILED
/opt/processing/build/build.xml:309: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/opt/processing/build/build.xml:365: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/opt/processing/java/build.xml:37: Problem: failed to create task or type antlr
Cause: the class org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.ANTLR was not found.
        This looks like one of Ant's optional components.
Action: Check that the appropriate optional JAR exists in
        -/opt/apache-ant-1.9.5/lib
        -/root/.ant/lib
        -a directory added on the command line with the -lib argument

Do not panic, this is a common problem.
The commonest cause is a missing JAR.

This is not a bug; it is a configuration problem
```

I have done what it says and placed placed the jar in the right place.
i did not see any ant documentation on how to pass the -lib on the commands line i even tried installing antlr via package manager which works i can type antlr and it spits out

```
Antlr parser generator   Version 1.33MR33   1989-2001
```

What can I do?

Comment: "Check that the appropriate optional JAR exists in" or "I have done what it says and placed placed the jar in the right place." proof of this actually being the case?

Comment: ant-antlr.jar and antlr-4.5.1-complete.jar are both in /opt/apache-ant-1.9.5/lib i swear.

Comment: Hmm, than we need an other solution.

Comment: when building processing i tacked -lib /opt/apache-ant-1.9.5/lib at the end with and without the jar to no avail, any suggestions?

Comment: ehm. Not sure but might the jar need execute permissions? :-)

Comment: @Rinzwind not in this case. Only for `java -jar some.jar`

Comment: i tried it anyway "chmod 777" still nothing good suggestion tho

Comment: What version of Ubuntu ?

Comment: It is release 14.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had the same message from gluegen package. Google got http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/a/Downloadantoptional1531jar.htm for only the class search. Install ant-optional/ant-optional-1.5.3-1.jar.zip( 608 k) solved this problem ( for the next).

Comment: This actually worked for me thank you why is that. I put it in the right folder and ran the build and got a new folder error saying  Check that the appropriate optional JAR exists in
        -/usr/share/ant/lib
        -/root/.ant/lib
so i put it in /usr/share/ant/lib and it worked

Comment: Hi MiMa, I am trying to build the same package, `gluegen`. But I have already `ant` and `ant-optional 1.9.7-3` installed..